# Issue with react-sortable-hoc in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I use sorting library: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc
I use basic example:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {SortableContainer, SortableElement, arrayMove} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({value}) => (
  <li tabIndex={0}>{value}</li>
));

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((value, index) => (
        <SortableItem key={`item-${value}`} index={index} value={value} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

class SortableComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
  };
  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState(({items}) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));
  };
  render() {
    return <SortableList items={this.state.items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />;
  }
}

export default SortableComponent;
```

But it's not woking in my IE. Items are rendered but Nothing happens on keydown or on drag.
I am Using latest version of library. 
Also my react app is rendered inside jquery base application's page. Could this be problem? but only for IE. Not sure If something is blocking library.

Has anyone faced same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some polyfills to make this library work in ie11. Following are the links to the polyfill code that need to be added.

Array.find: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Array.from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill

Also, which version are you using? I used the polyfills with version 1.0.0 and it worked fine. For newer versions, I could not make it work and not getting any errors as well.

Reference: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/450